# Null EntityManager/EJB Injected into MDB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1, weblogic12c, message-driven-bean

I have a message-driven bean (MDB) deployed to WebLogic 12.1.3. I tried to inject an entity manager into the MDB using the @PersistenceContext annotation, but the entity manager is null. I also tried injecting a simple stateless session bean and it too is null. However, the MessageDrivenContext is injected correctly.

What am I missing? From what I can tell searching SO and Google, you should be able to inject EJBs and entity managers into MDBs. I am able to inject them into other parts of the application just fine. Why not MDBs?

**Notes:**

- I am trying to use container-managed transactions
- The MDB is packaged with two others (that also don't work) in a single JAR that is within an EAR
- The JAR has a persistence.xml that works in other parts of the application
- The JAR has a beans.xml in it too
- I tried many combinations of the transaction annotations and ActivationConfig properties (below)

**MDB:**

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig =  {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="acknowledgeMode", propertyValue="Auto-acknowledge"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destinationJndiName", propertyValue="jms/MyTopic"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destinationType", propertyValue="javax.jms.Topic"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="subscriptionDurability", propertyValue="Durable"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="connectionFactoryJndiName", propertyValue="weblogic.jms.XAConnectionFactory"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="transaction-type", propertyValue="Container"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="trans-attribute", propertyValue="Required"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="trans-timeout-seconds", propertyValue="120"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="topicMessagesDistributionMode", propertyValue="One-Copy-Per-Application")
})
@TransactionTimeoutSeconds(120)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class MyMDB implements MessageListener {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="myPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Resource
    private MessageDrivenContext context;

    @EJB
    private HelloWorld helloWorld;

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void onMessage(final Message message) {

        //entityManager is null
        //context is NOT null
        //helloWorld (EJB) is null
    }
}
```

**persistence.xml:**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="myPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">

        <jta-data-source>MyDataSource</jta-data-source>

        <mapping-file>META-INF/queries.xml</mapping-file>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.lock.timeout" value="30000"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**EJB:**

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class HelloWorld {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="myPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello World";
    }


    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but I agree that the injection should work.  It seems odd that the container would inject the context field but not the entityManager/helloWorld fields and not give an error.  Do you have an ejb-jar.xml?  Guessing wildly, perhaps there's some annotation caching happening, so have you tried undeploying and redeploying the application from scratch?

Comment: No, there isn't an ejb-jar.xml. All of the configuration is specified in the ActivationConfig. I did try a complete reload and that didn't help either.

Comment: Well, I don't have an answer, but I can tell you that I have the exact same problem, while migrating from weblogic 12.1.1.0 (everything was fine) to 12.1.3.0 (same, entityManager is null).